# Angular Scope in Jquery

Tags: angularjs

I am having an requirement to retrieve the angular scope. Following is working perfectly fine in Chrome, Safari, IE. But in FF it is throwing error and not scope is coming as undefined.

`var scope = angular.element('cards-container').scope()`.

Please help!

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14807

Comment: Make sure to $compileProvider.enableDebugInfo = false

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the debugging mode in order to allow this

`$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false)`

check [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9515)